# YTD Query comparing this year to last year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to provide a percentage of growth from Last YTD to Current YTD

I have my current YTD query

```
select sum(total) from invoiceinfo
WHERE InvoiceDateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,GETDATE()), 0) AND GETDATE()
```

How do I query for last YTD for the same day as this year.  I imagine once I have this query I will then need to calculate the percentage of growth

Comment: `DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())` and so on

Comment: careful with getdate(), dont forget to strip the timestamps if needed.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  I don't see how that query answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Last YTD I believe you can use this query below.

You need to basically replace your `GETDATE()` with the same day of last year: `DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())`.

```
select sum(total) from invoiceinfo
WHERE InvoiceDateTime 
BETWEEN DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())), 0) 
AND DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())
```